# Using express, node.js and jade - style.css is not being displayed/found

Tags: css, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to figure out how to use node.js with jade right now, and I can't seem to get it to pull in the css stylesheet. My app.js looks like this:

```
/* * Module dependencies */ 
var http    = require("http"),
express = require('express') , 
stylus = require('stylus')

//create an app server
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
  //set path to the views (template) directory
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);

  app.use(stylus.middleware({
    debug: true,
    src: __dirname + '/views',
    dest: __dirname + '/public'
  }));  
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

//handle GET requests on /
  app.get('/', function(req, res){res.render('index.jade'); 
});
//listen on localhost:3000
app.listen(3000);
```

My layout.jade file looks like:

```
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body!= body
```

And my file structure is:

```
App
  -node_modules
  -public
    -css
      style.css
    -img
    -js
  -views
    -routes
    -stylesheets
      style.styl
    index.jade
    layout.jade
  app.js
  package.json
```

I'm getting the website to load properly, but the stylesheet isn't loading.

Comment: The path given to `express.static()` is missing a `/` -- `__dirname + '/public'` -- so it's probably trying to look for files in an `Apppublic` folder that doesn't exist. The [`path` module](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) can also help with avoiding that: `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))`.

Comment: I changed that to:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
but I'm getting "ReferenceError: path is not defined" when I make that change.

Comment: Sorry. You'll have to `require('path')` as you are with `http`, `express`, etc. since it isn't a [global](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html) in modules.

Comment: Ok, add:  path = require('path') and it is running, but the stylesheet still doesn't seem to be included.

Answer (score 3):

You want to change your line

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
```

to

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
> ```

shouldn't it be `href='/css/style.css'` instead?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This does provide an answer to the question if this typo is present in the original source code.

Comment: On the other hand, it might not, file structure is a bit confusing. Anyway, in some cases you can't really answer a question, you can only guess what the root cause is, and this one is as good guess as any.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same kind of problem, and for me, since I had the same line of code as you:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
```

I had to move my `css/` folder inside of the `public/` directory, because all public static files should be inside this directory.

Then, in my Jade file, I used this:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/style.css")
```

Does this work for you?